# Find Every Position of a Given Char Within an Array

Tags: c, char, substring, performance

I made a small function that fills an allocated block of memory containing every position of a given char within a given string and returns a pointer to the memory block.

The only problem with this function is that there is no way to check the size of the memory block; so I also made a function that counts the occurrence of a given char within a string.

Here is an example of use:

```
/*count occurences of char within a given string*/
size_t strchroc(const char *str, const char ch)
{ 
    int c = 0;
    while(*str) if(*(str++) == ch) c++;
    return c;
}

/*build array of positions of given char occurences within a given string*/
int *chrpos(const char *str, const char ch)
{
    int *array, *tmp, c = 0, i = 0;

    if(!(array = malloc(strlen(str) * sizeof(int)))) return 0x00;
    while(str[c])
    {
        if(str[c] == ch) array[i++] = c;
        c++;
    }
    if(!(tmp = realloc(array, i * sizeof(int)))) return 0x00;
    array = tmp;
    return array;
}

int main(void)
{
    char *str = "foobar foobar";                //'o' occurs at str[1], str[2], str[8], and str[9]
    int *array, b = 0, d;

    if(!(array = chrpos(str, 'o'))) exit(1);    //array[0] = 1, array[1] = 2, array[2] = 8, array[3] = 9

    /*
     * This is okay since I know that 'o'
     * only occures 4 times in str. There
     * may however be cases where I do not
     * know how many times a given char 
     * occurs so I figure that out before
     * utilizing the contents of array.
     * I do this with my function strchroc.
     * Below is a sample of how I would 
     * utilize the data contained within
     * array. This simply prints out str
     * and on a new line prints the given
     * char's location within the str 
     * array
     */

    puts(str);
    while(b < (int) strchroc(str, 'o'))         //loop once for each 'o' 
    {
        for(d = 0; d < (b == 0 ? array[b] : array[b] - array[b - 1] - 1); d++) putc((int) ' ', stdout);
        printf("%d", array[b]);
        b++;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
foobar foobar
 12     89
```

My only concern is that if one of these two functions fail, there is no way for the data to be used correctly. I was thinking about making the number of occurrences of `char` within the string an argument for `chrpos` but even then I would still have to call both functions.

I was wondering if anybody had any suggestions for a way to do this so that I only need one function to build the array.

The only way I can think of is by storing the number of char occurrences into `array[0]` and having `array[1] through array[char_occurences]` holding the positions of `char`.

If anybody has a better idea I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Not sure how you're using the final results - do you actually need to build the full list for future use, or would switching your approach to a scanner (find next occurrence of character after this position) work out? You'd have to pass a couple more (pointer) variables to maintain state between calls, but if that would work for your end use, it would solve the couple problems you're looking at.

Comment: It's just in this particular situation where I need the full list I think I'm going to just have to move the number of chars into array[0].

Comment: Why makes you think these two functions (I'm assuming you are speaking of chrpos and strchroc) would fail ?

Comment: And more to that, why don't you `return array;` if realloc fails ?

Comment: Just in case really, (what if malloc fails, etc).

Comment: That's a solid point :) thank you

Comment: You can't do this without a `malloc` so `chrpos` will always have this risk. `strchroc` would never fail on a normal string; you could test `str` before dereferencing it if you're worried though.

Comment: Thank you I've decided how I'm going to do this now; thanks for every ones help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in my comment the first thing is to save up the data anyway, in case you can't shrink the allocated memory :

```
if (!(tmp = realloc(array, i * sizeof(int))))
  return array;
return (tmp); //array = tmp; is useless
```

If you want to protect a bit more your strchroc function add a `if (!str) return 0;` at the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

You can change your function so that it also "returns" the number of occurrences found. While we cannot actually return multiple values from a function in C, we can pass a pointer as a parameter and have the function write down a value using that pointer:

```
int *chrpos(const char *str, char ch, int *found) {
    /* 
    ...
    */
    *found = i;
    return array;
}
```

Note that you don't need the `const` modifier for `ch`.